# Mysql query optiomization (to avoid using UNION ALL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Does exist any way how to optimize given query? I would like to get always all result from the `user` table and + also result form the `picture` table (if related exists). It is possible without using `UNION ALL`?

Lets consider following example

```
 +----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Drosos |
|  2 | Jack   |
+----+--------+

+----+---------+--------------+
| id | user_id | picture_name |
+----+---------+--------------+
|  1 |       1 | avatar.jpg   |
|  2 |       1 | avatar2.jpg  |
+----+---------+--------------+
```

Expected result

```
+--------+--------------+
| name   | picture_name |
+--------+--------------+
| Drosos | avatar.jpg   |
| Drosos | avatar2.jpg  |
| Drosos | NULL         |
| Jack   | NULL         |
+--------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

User

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Picture table

```
CREATE TABLE `picture` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `picture_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Query

```
SELECT u.name, p.picture_name FROM user u
INNER JOIN picture p ON p.user_id = u.id
UNION ALL
SELECT u.name, NULL FROM user u;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46d18a/1

Comment: Why do you need this output format?  The `Drosos NULL` record in the result set is hard to interpret.  What does it mean?  `Drosos` actually did match to something already.  The `UNION` might be your best bet here.

Comment: If you need `Drosos | NULL` in results, then `UNION ALL` is best. If you wouldn't need that row, then `LEFT JOIN` would be better.

Comment: It is needed in one of my applications (it is completely different context, I had to quite a lot simplify to make it understandable). Is better do it on the database level, then on the application level and iterate over the result.

Comment: Why do you think `UNION ALL` is bad? It expresses your requirements rather concisely

Comment: Where does the third `Drosos | NULL` come from? The alternative approach is using an `outer join`. This may or may not improve performance. `UNION ALL` isn't necessarily bad.

Comment: @caleth because it causes 2x `user` table scans. @Nick.McDermaid I had tried. this is not what I wanted.

Comment: Have you measured that as the performance bottleneck with your actual data? not with a toy example

Comment: @Caleth using `UNION ALL` over the data set containing ~ 150_000 rows the query is about ~15% slower (which is not too bad). I just want to know whether there is some better solution to tackle this problem.

Comment: 15% slower than what? a different result?

Comment: @Caleth compared to a query based on  `LEFT JOIN` and do the transformation of expected result on the application level

Comment: You need to clarify a lot of things. If you already tried LEFT JOIN and it's not what you wanted.... what do you mean? wrong result? Is the third `Drossos | NULL` in your example result set actually required?

Comment: @nick.McDermaid please, read carefully the issue description and try given example also SQL fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best optimization which I have achieved is with using "**materialized view**" and applied needed indexes. The query which used to take `~0.4000 sec`  now takes `~0.0025 sec`.

*Materialized views are not supported by MySQL so I had to create table table and trigger manually (which is not great but in my case was worth to do).*

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method to get what you're after, but it's really only to illustrate theat UNION ALL is probably your best solution anyway. This is SQL Server syntax which should be pretty close to MySQL

```
SELECT u.name, p.picture_name 
FROM user u
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 1 as C1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) As CJ
LEFT JOIN picture p ON p.user_id = u.id AND CJ.C1 = 1
```

This duplicates the user table with a cross join then attaches pictures to just one of the copies

If you didn't need that extra `Drosso | NULL` then a simple left join would be fine